# How should I interpret this operator equality?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $A$ is a fixed densely defined self-adjoint operator on a complex Hilbert space $\mathfrak{h}$.We are given a function $f \in C_{0}^{\infty}([0,\infty))$ with compact support and smooth such that $0 \le f \le 1$, $f(x) = 1$ if $0 \le x \le 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x \ge 2$.

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ be nonzero and consider the operator $h(A) = f(\lambda A)$. Denote by $1_{[x \le a]}$ the indicator function which is $1_{[x \le a]}(x) = 1$ if $x \in [0,a]$ and zero otherwise. My question is: how should I interpret the operator equality $1_{[A \le 2\lambda^{-1}]}h(A) = h(A)$? What does $1_{[A \le 2\lambda^{-1}]}$ even mean? I mean, an indicator function with respect to operators?

Comment: It seems like shorthand for an indicator function on the spectrum of $A$.

Comment: But is it a real-valued function? It comes "multiplied" by an operator $h(A)$.

Comment: It looks like it is a real-valued function being interpreted as a diagonal operator via pointwise multiplication that acts like the identity on the eigenspaces associated with the invariant subspaces corresponding to $\sigma(A) \leq 2\lambda^{-1}$ and zero otherwise. I agree the notation is confusing.

Comment: So, if I understood it correctly, the equality $1_{[A \le 2\lambda^{-1}]}h(A) = h(A)$ should mean $$\langle \psi, h(A)\psi\rangle = \int_{\sigma(A)}1_{[x \le 2\lambda^{-1}]}(x)h(x)d\mu_{\psi,\varphi}(x)$$ via the spectral theorem?